# Linq Query - Finding consecutive increasing values

Tags: linq

Say I have the following class:

```
internal class ModuleScrap
    {
        public System.DateTime ReadTime { get; set; }
        public int NetScrap { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like a Linq query that finds for me all NetScrap values that were greater than the NetScrap value before it, based on ReadTime. So, a query that looks something like this:

```
MyList
   .OrderBy(row => row.ReadTime)
   .Where (row => row.NetScrap > [The Previous NetScrap Value])
```

Is such a query possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, using [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) and `Skip` (assuming .NET 4):

```
// Avoid having to do the ordering twice
var ordered = list.OrderBy(row => row.ReadTime).ToList();

var greater = ordered.Zip(ordered.Skip(1), (x, y) => new { x, y })
                     .Where(p => p.y.NetScrap > p.x.NetScrap)
                     .Select(p => p.y);
```

Zipping a sequence with itself skipped one gives you pairs of consecutive elements:

```
Original           a  b  c  d  e  f
Original.Skip(1)   b  c  d  e  f  g
```

If you read each column from the above, you get the pairings. From there, you just need to select each value where the second entry's `NetScrap` is greater than the first.

Comment: I should have just posted my response, instead of stopping to ask questions. :P

This is the solution I was going to suggest, so +1

Comment: Okay, I wasn't totally missing something, this won't compile as it, it should be `.Where(p => p.y.NetScrap > p.x.NetScrap)      .Select(p => p.y);`

Comment: #offtopic but @Jon I'm watching your C#5 `async` talk right now.  Great stuff!

Comment: @Davy8: Cool - glad you're enjoying it. I love talking about async - but Wednesday was tiring!